# calculation of relative atomic masses in the periodic system

Tags: periodic-table, mass-spectrometry

If I now want to calculate the relative mass of c-13 based on the definition m(c-12) = 12amu, I need the q/m values of c-12 & c-13, where do I find these (I've looked everywhere on the internet)? Is this how all other amu's occurring in the PS are determined? How did that go before mass spectroscopy?

Comment: Masses of near all isotopes can be found on Wikipedia under titles "Isotopes of <element>", e.g. [Isotopes of carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_carbon)

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you, I can understand that it says that c-12 is exactly 12 amu, but my question was about how you now know that c-13 is 13.0033548352 amu. This cannot be a direct conclusion from the definition of amu, so you need a ratio between c-12 and c-13 (like the q/m ratio I'm looking for)

Comment: When you know one, you know the other.

Comment: @Poutnik Could you perhaps show me how you calculate m(c-13) using only the definition "m(c-12) = 12 amu"? ^^

Comment: I have not said you can do that. You use 12C mass and ratio of q/m ratios for 12C and 13C to get 13C mass. Or you use 12C and 13C masses to get the a/m ratios.

Comment: @Poutnik but on the wikipedia page you mentioned i can't find the q/m ratios. There are only: Nuclide, Z, N, Isotopic mass (Da), Half-life [resonance width], Decay mode, Daughter isotope, Spin and parity and Natural abundance (mole fraction).

Comment: I have not said those are there. They can be calculated.

Comment: @Poutnik yes, but then why did you comment at the first place if you don't respond to my question at all? My Question was "If I now want to calculate the relative mass of c-13 based on the definition m(c-12) = 12amu, I need the q/m values of c-12 & c-13, where do I find these..."

Comment: That is why it is called a comment and not  an answer. Comments do not try to provide an answer.

Comment: Your definition is not quite correct. You mean m(C-12) = 12 u. The old unit "amu" was based on oxygen and is no longer used.

Comment: ..that means m(12C) = 12 Da ([Daltons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_%28unit%29))

Comment: The exact mass of an isotope like $\ce{C-13}$ cannot be calculated. It is experimentally determined by mass spectroscopy. Why is it $13.003354$, and not $13.008888$, or $13.012345$ ? Nobody knows. The same thing can be said for all other nuclei.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about the measurement of carbon-13 mass. After long efforts of physicists and chemists (more than two centuries), it was decided that everyone will measure the atomic mass with respect to carbon-12, defined exactly as 12 g/mol. Once this value was set, every element was measured relative to this particular carbon isotope.

Before mass spectrometry, there was no idea that carbon has isotopes or oxygen has isotopes so this problem of measuring the relative mass of carbon-13 did not exist! Nobody knew about isotopes before 1913. The mass spectrometers, or the so-called parabola spectrographs were invented in 1912.

It is possible to measure the atomic weights by chemical means (one Nobel Prize) of all the elements. In fact the atomic mass of most of the elements (mixtures of isotopes) were known by pure simple and elegant chemistry, and simple mathematics of ratio and proportion long before MS was invented.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer :-) 
How exactly were the weights measured by chemical means? 

I just looked up the isotope B-11 on Wikipedia, there the mass was given with 11.009305167 u.

Now I wanted to calculate this mass myself, so I first thought that 5 protons and & neutrons correspond to about 11 u, the mass of the electron is known since the Millikan experiment in 1909, accordingly also the mass of the proton. Unfortunately, I do not know when the mass of the neutron was determined.
(5x1,6726*10^-24g + 6x1,6749*10^-24g + 5x9,1094*10^-28g) x N_a = 11,09094954u which is of (1/2)

Comment: course a little bit too much because of the binding energy later. 

So assuming mass spectroscopy does not yet exist, mass defect is not known but relative mass is based on c-12 isotope as it is today, would we say boron-11 has a relative mass of 11.09094954u? And also if the cathode ray and oil droplet experiment had never taken place would you say boron-11 has a mass of 11 amu?

Comment: Where can I find the q/m values of carbon 12 and any other element? Unfortunately I can't find these values anywhere on the internet. 
Because with this I could at least calculate the isotopic mass as given on Wikipedia for isotopes (m(Boron-11) = 11.009305167u) myself by simply calculating: (q/m of c-12)/(q/m of any other isotope) x 12 or?

Comment: If you want to know how we got here, go to wikipedia and look up “John Dalton” and “Dalton (unit)”. The history goes further back, but Dalton’s work is a reasonable start. As M. Farooq stated, it took centuries of research and refinement, by chemists and physicists, and we did not get get numerical values, with lots of digits, until late in the story. The whole thing is *vastly* too big to be answered in a Q and A site, i.e., here. So, good luck with your reading up on this fascinating history!

Comment: @iwab See also [Semi-empirical mass formula aka Gamow's liquid drop model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula)

Comment: @iwab, Can you write a separate question? I appreciate your thought process but refine your next question, read a little bit more because you are self answering many just like the binding energy. You cannot have q/m for Carbon-12. It is by definition.

Comment: @M.Farooq I think I have found the answer: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/04%3A_The_Structure_of_Atoms/4.15%3A_Measurement_of_Atomic_Weights here, for example, the mass of a c-13 isotope is calculated by initially making a reference measurement with c-12 and then comparing this with the measured value of c-13 in order to determine the mass: m(c-13)=(29.749 cm/27.454 cm)(12.000000)=13.0031u. This should be done in this way with every element, right?

Comment: @iwab, I think you are right. Today Fourier Transform Ion Cyclotron Resonance Mass Spectrometer can measure masses of single isotopes to several decimal places. This magnetic sector mass spectrometer was also high resolution.